# Compilation error in boost iostreams when building from source

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to build from source a Linux binary, that relies on Boost iostreams. Boost is also built from source on my machine. I get the following error message, which appears to be a compilation error in Boost:

```
g++  -g -O2   -o mkdssp src/dssp.o src/iocif.o src/mas.o src/mkdssp.o src/primitives-3d.o src/structure.o src/utils.o -lboost_date_time-mt -lboost_filesystem -lboost_iostreams-mt -lboost_program_options-mt -lboost_regex-mt -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lpthread  
src/mkdssp.o: In function `boost::iostreams::detail::bzip2_decompressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >::~bzip2_decompressor_impl()':
/usr/local/include/boost/iostreams/filter/bzip2.hpp:361: undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::detail::bzip2_base::end(bool, std::nothrow_t)'
src/mkdssp.o: In function `boost::iostreams::detail::bzip2_compressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >::~bzip2_compressor_impl()':
/usr/local/include/boost/iostreams/filter/bzip2.hpp:321: undefined reference to `boost::iostreams::detail::bzip2_base::end(bool, std::nothrow_t)'
```

I have seen similar posts elsewhere, but no recipes of a workaround. Note that I don't have sudo on my machine, so doing `rpm install this` or `yum install that` is not really an option for me; i guess what I am looking for is instructions on how to rebuild boost.

My versions:

- Boost 1.69.0
- bzip2-1.0.6 (also built from source)
- CentOS 7
- Linux 3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64

Thanks in advance

Comment: This looks like a failure to link with the boost library properly. Unless you're building boost itself, this cannot be "a compilation error in Boost" itself. You will need to examine your source's makefile or build script, figure out how it attempts to link with boost, then figure out how it should be linking with boost, and make the appropriate changes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `-L<boost-libs-dir> -Wl,-rpath=<boost-libs-dir>` to your linker command lines. `<boost-libs-dir>` is where the boost libraries you built reside, e.g. `/usr/local/lib` since your boost headers are in `/usr/local/include`.

If you didn't specify `--layout=system` when building boost, then you also need to specify the version numbers in the library names, e.g. `-lboost_thread-gcc-mt-1_61` or something like that. Read [Boost Library Naming](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#library-naming) for full details.